# Adding x.509 Certificate to Microsoft Certificate Store

Tags: x509certificate

I have x.509 Certificate that is to be added to the Microsoft Certificate store. How to do that programmatically ? Please post the code for doing that.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

We aren't supposed to google this for you.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms148583(v=vs.100).aspx